# Grafana PromQL Cannot read property 'result' of undefined

Tags: .net, prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm currently learning prometheus and try to visualize its metrics using Grafana and PromQL, but every time I put my queries metrics, it always showing error
`Cannot read property 'result' of undefined`, i searched and tried some queries in internet, and all of them makes no difference. I wonder where i go wrong, since this is my first time using prometheus and grafana, here's some setting i used

First, this is my prometheus config, in `.net framework`.

```
public class PrometheusConfig
{
    private static readonly Counter counter = Metrics.CreateCounter("initial_counter", "counter to initiate Prometheus");

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var server = new MetricServer(port: 1234);
        server.Start();

        counter.Inc();
    }

    public static void RegisterFilter(HttpFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new PrometheusFilter());
    }
}
```

Here my prometheus metrics i want to visualize

[image]

this is my grafana data source

[image]

and finally, this is my panel graph
[image]

can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This error usually means that grafana fails to query the API.

In your case, it is because the URL shouldn't include the `/metrics`. This URL is used for scraping Prometheus internals.

The correct URL should be the base path of Prometheus: `http://localhost:1234`

Comment: i got 404 not found if i remove `/metrics`. I tried `:9090` also

Comment: Did you try a curl on the same server as you grafana install ? It could be that your Prometheus is not bound to the correct interface or wrongly routed. (And yes 9090 is the default Prometheus port but I assumed this was an example)

Comment: Did you set a Prometheus instance to scrape your software ? Grafana uses the `/api` of Prometheus, not the raw metric endpoint of your application.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem Michael. How to set  instance to scrape my api?
I'm learning from this https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net#installation , which part is explained about scraping my api instead of just publishing to metric endpoint? or is there another reference that i can follow?

Comment: You have to [install prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/) and tell it to scrape your api (using [static config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#static_config) by example). And then point your grafana to the prometheus URL. See the architecture overview in the doc).